# How do I run a Python script on the Azure server?

Tags: python, web, server

I am new to Microsoft Azure. I created a bot in Python that takes a message in Messenger from a page that I created in Facebook, processes each message posted, into a function that produces output to present back to Messenger (through Webhook).

Since I have no web space, my Python script is ran locally on my machine, and I am using local hosting to 'communicate' back and forth in Messenger and using my local hosting address for my Webhook link. I also need the script running locally on my machine and local hosting in order for my bot to work in Facebook Messenger.

```
I was wondering if there is a way to run my script directly from a server on Azure when and if I get web space, instead of from my machine locally (as I THINK Azure is the place to do this from), and how do I run my script from there instead on a 'constant basis'? Thank you for any assistance.
```

Comment: What have you tried? Not specific enough for help. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I found a site called pythonanywhere, but am now trying to figure out how to host my bot from the pythonanywhere site, instead of from my computer (local hosting). When I local host my bot (using ngrok), it works fine; I post something in Messenger on a Facebook page I created, and I get a response back from my bot. The problem happens when I try to get my bot to work from the pythonanywhere site. 

   I changed the Callback Url in Webhook to https://ensurdfrndship.pythonanywhere.com/ (my site), noticed I don't need a verify token, but when I type something in messenger, nothing happens.